# Joining on one column and returning records that are not mutual

Tags: mysql

What is the easiest way to select all records via JOIN on a column, and returning the values that they **do not** share, i.e. are unique to each table's column?

What I'm looking for is something similar to PHP's `array_diff()`;

So if the table columns contain the following values:

```
Table 1 column values: 1, 45, 7, 99, 31

Table 2 column values: 100, 3, 7, 31, 22
```

Results should give me the following values back: `1, 45, 99, 100, 3, 31, 22` (i.e. skip the mutual values `7` and `31`).

Comment: So you want a result corresponding to the 5th diagram... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html MySQL doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN, but you can emulate it fairly easily in a couple of (widely discussed) ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the text "returning the values that they do not share, i.e. are unique to each table's column?".

There are several way to approach this.  Perhaps the most obvious is to take everything from the first table not in the second and vice versa:

```
select value
from table1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 where table2.value = table1.value)
union all
select value
from table2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 where table2.value = table1.value);
```

If you don't have duplicates in either table, then another approach is to union the tables together and then return the ones that only appear once:

```
select value
from (select value from table1 union all
      select value from table2
     ) t
group by value
having count(*) = 1;
```

EDIT:

The equivalent of array_diff is simply:

```
select value
from table1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 where table2.value = table1.value)
```

It is not symmetric.

Comment: Could you make a little explanation - why use `UNION ALL`? `array_diff()` isn't symmetric (and so should be result) - or am I missing some point?

Comment: @AlmaDo . . . I misinterpreted how the OP described what `array_diff()` does.  Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: Great way to emulate the missing `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL. Thank you Gordon.

Answer (score -1):

Use NOT IN.

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```